# Attempting to display top 2 average prices

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to display the top 2 average prices, however I am having an issue as the two columns I need to display are from different tables and the join is giving me error messages when I attempt solutions from other threads. For example:

```
Customer Table          Order Table
CID,CNAME               OID,CID,OPRICE    
1,  JOHN                 1,  1,  2.50
2,  JEFF                 2,  1,  3.40
3,  ROB                  3,  2,  4.20
                         4,  3,  3.50
```

This is what I have got so far but it displays all the results not just the top 2.

```
SELECT CNAME,AVG(OPRICE)
FROM CUSTOMER, ORDER
WHERE CUSTOMER.CID=ORDER.CID
GROUP BY CNAME;
```

The result I am after would be:

```
CNAME,AVG(OPRICE)
JEFF,  4.20
ROB,   3.50
```

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, learn proper `join` syntax.  *Never* use a comma in a `FROM` clause.  *Always* use `JOIN` and `ON`.

Then, in Oracle 12C+, you can do:

```
SELECT c.CNAME, AVG(o.OPRICE)
FROM CUSTOMER c JOIN
     ORDER o
     ON c.CID = o.CID
GROUP BY c.CNAME
ORDER BY AVG(o.OPRICE) DESC
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

Earlier versions require a subquery:

```
SELECT CNAME, avg_oprice
FROM (SELECT c.CNAME, AVG(o.OPRICE) as avg_oprice
      FROM CUSTOMER c JOIN
           ORDER o
           ON c.CID = o.CID
      GROUP BY c.CNAME
      ORDER BY AVG(o.OPRICE) DESC
     ) c
WHERE rownum <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

More recent Oracle versions have `FETCH FIRST`:

```
SELECT CNAME,AVG(OPRICE) as AVGPRICE
FROM CUSTOMER, ORDER
WHERE CUSTOMER.CID=ORDER.CID
GROUP BY CNAME
ORDER BY AVGPRICE DESC
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
```